# How to use on the fly jquery object with jquery template?

Tags: jquery, templates, object

my jquery template displays [object Object] when I pass the following jquery anchor object.

```
    moreinfoAnchor = $("<a></a>");
    moreinfoAnchor.attr('id', 'moreLink-' + this.id);
    moreinfoAnchor.text("test");
```

jquery template code:

```
$("#test").tmpl({
   link: moreinfoAnchor
});
```

How do I display actual anchor with jquery template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Build your anchor tag with jQuery:

```
var moreinfoAnchor = $("<a></a>")
  .attr({
    'href' : 'http://www.example.com',
    'id' : 'moreLink'
  })
  .text("test");
```

Turn your jQuery anchor tag into a plain string:

```
var plainString = $('<div>')
  .append( moreinfoAnchor.clone() ).remove().html();
```

Then apply the template:

```
$("#test").tmpl({
  link: plainString
}).appendTo('#thediv');
```

You'll also have to make sure your template is set up using the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/) template tag, something like this:

```
<script id="test" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div>{{html link}}</div>
</script>
```